# Power BI Mobile Only Visuals

Tags: mobile, powerbi

I have a report that I want to have different functionality between the mobile and desktop versions.  I've found that if I hide the visual while in development, it stays hidden in the mobile version after publication. Is there a way to have a visual appear ONLY on the mobile version, but be hidden on the desktop version?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way only to show in Mobile, but not in the desktop. Only show in desktop and not in Mobile. The visibility of the object is cannot be set individually on desktop or mobile. If you add it to the mobile view, then hide it in the desktop view, when you go back to the mobile view it is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't officially show a visual in mobile and hide it on the desktop.

However, as a workaround trick you can "hide" visuals by placing them behind other visuals.

- Shrink the size of the visual you want to hide (so it's easier to hide behind another visual without sticking out).
- Drag the visual over the top of another visual that you want to be visible.
- Make sure the "hidden" visual is sent to the back (Format/Send to Back).

In order to find (and edit) your visual in the future you can drag a selection box around the page. As long as your selection box fully encompasses the hidden visual it will be selected when you release. After releasing the selection box you will be able to see the "hidden" visual and you can edit it.

WARNING - This will make it harder for someone else to find and edit the visual in the future so please be careful how often you do this. While not good to do regularly it can get you out of a pinch.